# Value of TempData becomes null after "Redirect"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am facing issues with **TempData** after **Redirect**.

```
public ActionResult LoginCredentials()
{
    // Calling "SetError()" in catch(), if password mismatch.                        
    try{}

    catch()
    {
      return SetError();
    }   
}

public ActionResult SetError()
{
    // set the value of TempData as "true"                        
    TempData["error"] = true;
    return Redirect("/Login");                
}


public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["useError"]= TempData["error"]; // at this point TempData["error"] is null.
    ...
}
```

In SetError() value of TempData is successfully set as true, issue takes place after "Redirect", value becomes "null" and I can't use it anymore.

Comment: Please post your code for controller class here...

Comment: Whatever I had I have posted it.

Comment: TempData["error"] in the (Index) function will be null because (SetError) function did not excute.

Comment: Hard to understand what your trying to do here. It should be `return RedirectToAction("SetError);` not `return SetError();`, but then all that method does is a redirect again, so why not just `catch() { TempData["error"] = true; return RedirectToAction("Index); }` in the `LoginCredentials()` method?

Comment: @user3106445   I tried doing exactly what you did and it works fine for me, the issue may be something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. maybe the browser is cookieless
2. the data in a TempDataDictionary object persists only from one request to the next, unless you mark one or more keys for retention by using the Keep method, accoding to your code, if you redirect to login page, and then redirect to index, the value will be null. you can only read it at login page.

Comment: I am using TempData once, index is nothing but the view of the controller.

Comment: @user3106445  TempData:Represents a set of data that persists only from one request to the next.    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx  **Redirec to login is the first request, redirect to index from the login is the second request**

Comment: **I have marked this answer, because now I have redirected directly to  index page.**

Comment: So does TempData still become null even if it was never read?

Comment: I was visiting website on http when <httpCookies requireSSL="true" /> was enabled in web.config.

Comment: @user1794106  no, at the end of the request, keys has read will be removed. the question above is redirect to the login page which may clear the session or read the tempdata. then it will be null at the next request

Comment: This will occur when using the Brave browser.

Answer (score 7):

```
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
                    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                    //options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

turn off options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
```

this worked for me

Comment: This answer allows you to bypass the `CheckConsentNeeded` for TempDataProvider Cookie https://stackoverflow.com/a/75835861/23082833

Answer (score 2):

I find .Net Core incredibly problematic.
I had to turn this off in the Configuration

```
options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
```

and it worked when I used Redirect to navigate to another page.

However on refreshing the page the TempDate or ViewData lose their value. But when I reassigned it to itself in the "View" it worked:

```
@{
TempData["somevalue"] = TempData["somevalue"];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use RedirectToAction

```
public ActionResult SetError()
{
// set the value of TempData as "true"                        
   TempData["error"] = true;
   return RedirectToAction("YourViewName");                
 }
```

Comment: It is also null when using RedirectToAction

Answer (score 1):

Setting the cookie as essential in `CookieTempDataProviderOptions` Solved the issue for me.

```cs
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = _ => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict;
});
services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.cookietempdataprovideroptions.cookie?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand `ViewData` saves data only after redirect, not when just another Http request occur. So inside `Login` method(where you redirect to) this `ViewData["useError"]` have to be available, but `Index` method is just another method which is executed during another http request.That's why `ViewData["useError"]` is empty

You can use Session if you want to store data between different Http requests

Comment: The question is asking about `TempData`. `TempData` is a storage container for data that needs to be available to a separate HTTP request whereas `ViewData` is a container for data to be passed from the `PageModel` to the content page.