# Why are integers passed via temp data defaulting to 0?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

I have been building this card game as a web application with a GUI using ASP.NET Core. I would like a card object with random values to be generated, including a random value, and for the user to be returned to the view with those values displayed on the blank card.

At the moment, a temp data variable named `TempData["CardValue"]` is set up that stores the random value inside the controller, in the `PlayTurn()` action. It is populated with a positive integer, e.g. 8. But when I pass the contents of `TempData` to my Create view, the `TempData["CardValue"]` is listed as 0. Is there some sort of conversion going on, or parsing that is taking place?

My Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }   

        public static string GetShortName(string name)
        {
            string result = name.Substring(0, 1);

            return result;
        }
        public static Card CreateCard()
        {
            Card[] card1 = new Card[11];
            Random rnd1 = new Random();

            Array suitvalues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)); // generates a random suit
            Suit randomSuit = (Suit)suitvalues.GetValue(rnd1.Next(suitvalues.Length));

            var random = new Random();

            var min = 2;
            var max = 11;

            var i = random.Next(min, max);

            var card = new Card()
            {
                Suit = randomSuit,
                Value = i,
                DisplayName = GetShortName(randomSuit.ToString())
            };

            return card;
        }
        public IActionResult PlayTurn()
        {
            var card = CreateCard(); // creates a random card
            TempData["CardName"] = card.DisplayName;
            TempData["CardValue"] = card.Value;
            TempData["CardSuit"] = card.Suit.ToString();
            return Redirect("Create");
        }
```

My View:

```
    @model SnapCardGame.Models.Card
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome to the Card Page!</h1>

    @if (@TempData["CardName"] != null)
    {
        <a asp-controller="Card" asp-action="PlayTurn" class="card">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    @TempData["CardName"] 
                </li>
                <li>@TempData["CardValue"]</li>
                <li>@TempData["CardSuit"]</li>
            </ul>
        </a>

    }
    else
    {
        <a asp-controller="Game" asp-action="PlayTurn" class="card">
            &nbsp;
        </a>
    }

    <a asp-controller="Game" asp-action="PlayTurn" class="card">
        &nbsp;
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: To get good results from Random it must not be called in quick succession as by default it gets seeded from the system time. Assuming all cards get creates in a tight loop this will be one mistake..

Comment: Please post your `Configure` and `ConfigureServices` methods - I suspect you haven't configured `TempData` correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the right time for ViewData, ViewBag, Session, TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676924/what-is-the-right-time-for-viewdata-viewbag-session-tempdata)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Startup.cs` (or in `Program.cs` if you are using .NET 6), find where you configure your service (often in `Startup.cs - Configure()` method)

Use `app.UseCookiePolicy()` after the `app.UseMVC()`

```
// Startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
// ...
   app.UseMVC();
   app.UseCookiePolicy();
// ...
}
```

The problem is with your `Redirect` method. The data in `TempDataDictionary` persists only from one request to the next, unless you mark one for retention by using the [Keep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#tempdata) method;

Base on the [TempData document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#tempdata-providers).

> The cookie-based TempData provider is enabled by default.

So you have to enable **Cookie** in order to make `TempData` work across your views.

Also, I found some prominent solutions that you can try if the solution above does not work

- [Value of TempData becomes null after "Redirect"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60220643/6532416)
- [TempData not working](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8233)